# PHP retrieves the same row multiple times instead of retrieving all table's rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, data-retrieval

I am trying to print all members reports (complains) to the admin in this form:

sender name:...
reported user name:...

First I wanted to select each sender name directly from complaint table(using for loop), then find the matched reported user name and print all the reports in this way.
Note that I am not saving the sender name and reported user name at the same table so I need to do mysql join in order to find reported user name.

```
<?php

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaint  "); 
$ln = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);

if($ln > 0){
$results = array();
$results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results);

for($i=0;$i<$ln;$i++){

$SenderName = mysql_query("SELECT m_name FROM member  WHERE (`m_id`LIKE '".$results[1]."') "); 
$fetchA = mysql_fetch_array( $SenderName, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$ReportedUserId = mysql_query("SELECT r.d_id FROM ride r, complaint c WHERE  r.r_id= c.r_id"); 
$fetchB = mysql_fetch_array($ReportedUserId , MYSQL_ASSOC);
//Afer finding ID I use it to select name
$dname = mysql_query("SELECT m_name FROM member  WHERE (`m_id` LIKE '%".$fetchB['d_id']."%') "); 
$fetchDname = mysql_fetch_array($dname, MYSQL_ASSOC);?>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">  

              <?php echo 'From:';  ?>
                <?php echo $fetchA['m_name'];  ?></li>

                 <li data-theme="c" >  
                   <?php echo 'Reported user Name: ';   ?>
                    <?php echo  $fetchDname['m_name'];  ?>

            </li>
            </ul>
```

The output that I get from this code is the first row  of the table complaint printed multiple ($ln) times like :

- Nada
- Ali
- Nada
- Ali 

  ....until $ln

Why It doesn't go to the next line although I am using loop?
I tried the queries in database and it works so the problem is not from db.
I am ready to write more details if needed :)

My Schema:

```
Member(m_id, m_name, ...etc)
Ride(r_id, p_id ....etc) *p_id refers to m_id
Complaint(c_id, d_id ..etc)*d_id refers to m_id
the idea is member reports member in a ride
```

Comment: Did you forget to close the bracket for your For loop, or is just missing when you copy-pasted it here ?

Comment: Because you're only calling `mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)` once outside the loop...!?

Comment: No it is just missed here

Comment: You are really doing this in a poor manner.  My guess is you can get all the data you are after with a single query by joining complaint and ride tables to your member table. Forget about the PHP code for a second and step back to look at the query.

Comment: @Najd If you edit your question to better show you table schema and sample data, I would imagine you will be better query suggestion and can get rid of all the nested loop non-sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awww I did find the query guys Thank You
That is it

```
$name = mysql_query("SELECT m.m_name
FROM member m
INNER JOIN ride r
on m.m_id = r.d_id
INNER JOIN complaint c
on r.r_id = c.r_id
 ");
```

Now I need to know how to go throght it using the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating over your original result set.  Move `$results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results);` inside of your `for` loop and you should start to see your desired output.

I would like to say, however, that you might want to look into offloading some of your logic to your database by using `JOIN` statements.  It is difficult to say without seeing your underlying database schema, but it is generally not a good idea to have multiple database queries when one would be capable of retrieving the data that you need.

Lastly, the `mysql_fetch_array` statements are deprecated, so you should also look into the use of either the PHP PDO or the mysqli extension.

Comment: I did and it works to retrieve the correct sender name but the reported user name is not changing.

Comment: You need to add to your query for the ReportedUserId to include something like `AND c.sender_name = $SenderName`.  Again, it is difficult to say for certain without seeing your underlying database schema.  To revisit the issue, though, you really do need to read about joining database tables.  It will make your logic much simpler and probably faster.  In other words, Mike Brant is dead on when he says that you are doing this in a poor manner.  Here is are good places to start http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Thanks for the links and the complete answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change $results[1] to $results[$i] in the first line of your loop.